# Is there a MySQL variable for the current SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I would like to create a trigger in MySQL that can filter through and log SQL statements (like all updates) and write the SQL statement to a column in another table (VARCHAR).  Is there a variable or function in MySQL that provides the current SQL statement string?

Comment: If you want audit you include thet code to save the sql statement in the tool doing the call.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is there a variable or function in MySQL that provides the current SQL statement string?

A: No, there's no variable or function (or any built in mechanism) that allows the body of a MySQL TRIGGER to retrieve the SQL text of the statement that caused the trigger to be fired (the currently executing statement).

A `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` in the body of the trigger won't get it either; the SQL shown in the return for that will show the statement that is getting the processlist.  (If we wanted to use `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` to get the SQL, that would have to be from a *separate* session. And there's no built in mechanism to achieve that from within the body of the TRIGGER.

---